# Pressing Ctrl + Shift aligns text right in Outlook and Lync

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010, lync

I'm used to switching languages with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but whenever I press <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> in Outlook or Lync, all my text gets aligned right and there's no way to revert the effect but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> out of it.

This does not apply to Word. <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> is not affected. <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> messes everything up regardless of my key bindings.

Another weird thing I've noticed is that I had some Asian ninja languages installed, which would sometimes appear when switching the layout (various dialects of Chinese), but weren't listed in **Text Services and Input Languages**. I fixed that by adding and then removing them, as it is described [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cannot-remove-chinese-japanese-and-korean-from/ba66a078-8be6-4866-9aef-03a091a66c8a?rtAction=1392982820488), but that didn't help the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, fixing this was as simple as disabling a single service called **Microsoft IME Dictionary Update**. Have no idea what it's for (though I know how it got there - corporate Windows installation... bloatwarefest), as there's no description and not much info online (something related to Asian languages), but I haven't noticed any negative effects. [Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/95082-language-bar-windows-7-problem-2.html).