# Disable the Ctrl-Shift keyboard shortcut for right-to-left formatting

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-word-2010

When writing an e-mail message in Outlook 2010, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> on the right hand side of the keyboard changes formatting to right-to-left (as would be required for e.g. Arabic, Hebrew, etc.). Same occurs in Word 2010.

The problem is, I never need right-to-left formatting — but I often press these keys by accident, and then my text gets formatted right-to-left, which is most annoying.

How do I disable this keyboard shortcut?

I have looked in Options > Language, and in Control Panel > Region and Language settings, but have not found any mention of this keyboard shortcut.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/719871/pressing-ctrl-shift-aligns-text-right-in-outlook-and-lync) is similar but there is no unambiguous solution there, and my question does **not** deal with changing languages or keyboard layout.

Comment: you need to go into the "Advanced settings" within the region and language settings, then click "Change Language bar hot keys"

In "Text Services and Input Languages" click "Change Key Seqquence" button and disable the the key sequence.

Comment: @NabilAziz: Are you sure? As far as I can tell, those things change the language and/or keyboard layout. I’ve already disabled those two keyboard shortcuts. My question is about the keyboard shortcut for *right-to-left formatting*, not the same thing, I think.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, but my cursor jumped to the right in basically any window. I found that it is not a Region and Language setting but a Microsoft Office language setting. I have a very old Office XP. I had to go to Microsoft Office XP - Language settings, and remove the right-to-left writing languages from the allowed list of languages. After that the problem was fixed.

Comment: > Microsoft Office XP - Language settings - where is that "Language settings"?